# Are mulitple window.onload events in a FIFO or chain?

Tags: javascript

What really happens on multiple calls of `window.onload`? IE

```
function onLoadHandler(mMethod){
    var previous = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {

        if( previous ) previous();

        mMethod();
    }
}
```

If I use `window.onload = function() { /* print to console */ };` before I call my `onLoadHandler()` five (5) each call printing to the console  telling me which call this is. It prints to the console in order. Even if I write a second `onLoadHandler2()` and call it 5 additional times. Everything is printed in the correct order meaning in the order of call including the `window.onload` event first called.

I can't figure out what is happening here. It is a FIFO stack? Does each call get put in a stack and the first in is the first out therefore printed to the console in correct order?

Comment: It will have FIFO behaviour. Basically the code is taking whatever is there previously before overwriting it, calling that first, then calling the passed in method. You could repeat that pattern arbitrarily. `window.onload` can only ever have a single value, which is why this stuff is required.

Comment: "Required?" What about `window.addEventListener`?

Comment: "What really happens on multiple calls of window.onload" - this doesn't make sense because `onload` is only ever invoked once: by the browser. You could manually call it yourself, I suppose.

Comment: window.onload can only be called once when onLoadHandlr is called ten times is it not calling window.onload ten times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What really happens on multiple calls of window.onload?

You are making this more complicated than it is. `window.onload` is only called once by the browser. If `window.onload` resolves to a function, then that function  will be called. Nothing special is going on.

If the function assigned to `window.onload` calls others functions, those will be called as well (of course).

What you are doing in your code is that you are "preserving" the previous value of `window.onload` and explicitly calling it (`previous()`) if it exists. If you didn't do that, then only `mMethod()` would be called, not matter what the previous value of `window.onload` was.

Comment: I think you are saying if I called my function ten times the latest call would preserve the privious calls. Sort of like the 'next' call is added to the end of the list of calls. A.B.C.D next call we will use E therefore A.B.C.D.E  E preserving the privious calls ahead of it itself. This would mean A runs first then B and so forth. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yeah basically. If you moved `if( previous ) previous();` *after* `mMethod();` then the order would be the other way round. So it's really you who implements that FIFO queue.